# non-numeric tick marks in R

Tags: r, graph, plot, axis

Newbie Question!

I'm trying to plot a line graph, but the tick-labels on the x-axis have to be non-numeric. How can I do this? So far I have this:

```
plot(disparitybin$Variance[1,], type="l", xlim=c(0,5.0), ylim=c(0, 0.05), frame=FALSE, xlab="Time", xaxt='n', yaxt='n', ylab="Dispairty (Sum of Variance)", main="Dispairty Through Time", cex.lab=1.25, cex.main=1.75)

axis(1, pos=0, las=0)

axis(2, pos=0, las=2)
```

I'm trying to specify the names of each tick mark along the x-axis: Eocene, Oligocene, Miocene, Pliocene. How do I get the labels control for the axis() command to accept this info?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: first example under `?axis`: `plot(1:4, rnorm(4), axes = FALSE); axis(1, 1:4, LETTERS[1:4])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `axis` as follows:

```
axis.labels <- c("Eocene", "Oligocene", "Miocene", "Pliocene")
axis(1, labels=axis.labels, pos=0, las=0)
```

This assumes that you are plotting exactly four points of data.  Also, you were correct to make the call to `axis` **after** the call to `plot`.